# Sublime Text, Python: Interactive shell (when running build) doesnt work

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, interactive-shell

I just installed sublime text and start playing with it, using python code. I dabbled with the `Python.sublime.build` file that contains the commands to run code.

I wanted to use `"shell_cmd": "python -i \"$file\""` so that once the script has run, the shell drops into an interactive session that allows me to inspect variables.

However if I do that, I can see the `>>>` typical of an interactive session and type after it, but the `enter` command doesn't work. I tried `shift enter`, or `ctrl enter` but similarly it is simply adding a line break, instead of of processing what I have typed on the line.

Anyone knows how I could make the interactive python shell work with sublime3?

Comment: The specific answer to your question is that you can't do what you want; when you run a program from within Sublime, the `stdin` of the running process is not connected to anything, so you can't pass it input. You need to run what you're doing externally or use something like SublimeREPL to simulate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thx guys, this solved it